# How can i pass dynamic params to react IndexRedirect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-router, axios

Here is an *example* *code*

**Route.js**

```
 <Route onEnter={requireLogin}>
      <Route path="/" component={main}>
          <IndexRedirect to="/user/:id" />
          <Route path="/user/:id" component={User} />
          <Route path="/partner/:id" component={Partner} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
```

**Main.js**

```
<div>
   {this.props.children}
</div>
```

In this main component,
i get value of ***(:id) id*** in ***componentWillMount()***
and in the same time i stored that value in redux store..

and i ve set condition for not rendering props.children unless **id is set in store**...

and am planning to get id value from **store** in **Routes.js** page and pass id in IndexRedirect like this..

**`<IndexRedirect to={`/user/${id}`} />`**

is it the best way to do it?

What are the other way to pass dynamic params id to `<IndexRedirect>`

Comment: What's the react-router version you are using?

Comment: react-router version 2.1.2